# If $B_a$ is a basis for the topology on $X_a$, how to show that $\{\prod b_a\mid b_a\in B_a\}$ is a basis for the box topology on $\prod X_a$?

Tags: general-topology

If not, what is a counterexample?

I'm trying to prove Theorem 19.2 from Munkres's *Topology*.

> Suppose the topology on each $X_a$ is given by a basis $B_a$. The collection $B$ of all sets of the form $\prod b_a$, where $b_a \in B_a$ for all $a$, will serve as a basis for the box topology on $\prod X_a$.

At first, I thought it was enough just to show that $B$ satisfies the basis definition. Do I also need to show that the topology generated by $B$ equals the box topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to show that for every element $x$ in the product and every box topology neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there is an element of $B$ such that $x\in B\subseteq U$.

**Edit**: Once you've done that, you need only confirm that every element of $B$ is open in the box topology on $X$--which should be a fairly simple task, as elements of a basis $B_a$ of $X_a$ are necessarily open in $X_a$. Then by Lemma 13.2 of Munkres, $B$ will be a basis for the box topology on $X$, as desired.

Note that this last detail is actually *essential* to include! (I neglected to mention it because it should be clear that the elements of $B$ are open in the box topology on $X$, but in hindsight, I shouldn't have omitted that detail. Apologies for any confusion!) For example, if we take $B'$ to be the set of all singletons $\{x\}$ (for $x\in X$), the set $B'$ rather trivially satisfies the condition I mentioned in the first place, but while it *is* a basis, it is a basis for the *discrete* topology--strictly a finer topology (in general) than the box topology.

All the condition I mentioned at first *really* shows is that *if* $B$ is a basis for some topology, then it generates a topology finer than the box topology on $X$ (possibly strictly finer). Knowing that the elements of $B$ are open in the box topology allows us to conclude that (1) $B$ *is* a basis for a topology on $X$, and that (2) the generated topology is coarser than (so equivalent to, since also finer than) the box topology on $X$.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused by the wording of the question. Isn't it asking if the topology generated by the given basis equals the box topology?

Comment: @sli: Yes, provided that you recognize that this includes showing that $B$ is a base at all. It’s asking you to show that $B$ is a base for a topology $\tau$ on the product **and** that this $\tau$ is the box topology.

Comment: Apologies, @sli. I left out one fairly critical detail--which fortunately is almost trivial to see. See my edit for the addition.

Comment: @sli: No problem at all! Did you get through it, then?

Comment: @Cameron: Yeah. I wish Munkres would give a heads-up when he defines "X is blah and blah" then later refers (and shortens) it as "X is blah." For first time learners, It's really confusing and annoying.

Comment: @sli: I hear you on that. It's fairly standard practice, and it's something you'll get used to. Often, the text'll make brief mention in passing ("hereinafter referred to as 'blah'"), but sometimes there's just a shortening with no warning.